# ROS could not find the executable file

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, 
I made all the steps of the ROS tutorial that are described in the ROS Wiki (create a catkin workspace and a listener and talker node). Now I tried to Use the programme presented here: https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard. 
I copied the files into the src foldeer in my catkin workspace. This one includes now the folder with the named files and a folder "beginner_tutorials" with all the files of the tutorials. After using catkin_make and source devel/setup.bash, I started the node with "rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py" but then ROS told me that "Couldn't find executable named teleop_twist_keyboard.py below ...". 
I tried some other locations for the folder but nothing works. Could you give me an advice how to solve this Problem? 
 
Regards,

Rick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296714/ros-could-not-find-the-executable-file/) by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-07-09**:
Please post the `CMakeLIsts.txt` and `package.xml`. Most probably you forgot to adapt this...
(Edit your question and format the copied files, obviously removing any comments, with the preformatted text button 1010101).

**Comment by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on 2018-07-09**:
Could you tell me how I have to do this? I did not changed anything.These both files are like in the example above.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-07-09**:
What? Posting the `CMakeLists.txt`?
Also include the output of `tree -d <PATH/TO/YOUR/WORKSPACE>/src`.

**Comment by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on 2018-07-09**:
The CMakeLists in the project folder is like in the example above. I think that I don't need to paste it again. In the src folder is also a CMakeLists file. Should I include these lines in this one or in the file that is located in the project folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you edit your CMakeLists.txt file to add it as an executable? You should have the following in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
   teleop_twist_keyboard.py
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Also the suitable dependencies in package.xml
Look at both the CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files from the [teleop package](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard) that you presented.
Also be more specific on how you added the **teleop_twist_keyboard** package. You said "I copied the files into the src foldeer in my catkin workspace". Did you clone/copy the whole package or just the files from it? The ROS structure is that you should have packages inside your **catkin_ws/src** . In your case you should have 2 packages there. One being **beginner_tutorials** and the other **teleop_twist_keyboard**. If this is the case, delete both devel and build folders, then do a catkin_make and source devel/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on 2018-07-09**:
Hi,the four lines (catkin_install...) are already in the CMakeLists file that is located in the folder where also the python-file is located. I downloaded the files and put them in a folder without changing any file of it. Could you tell me which lines I have to add to the files of the example?

**Comment by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on 2018-07-09**:
The structure of the folders is like you already said. That's why I deleted the build and the devel folder and used catkin_make and source devel/setup.bash, but I get the same errors.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-09**:
open a new terminal and try:

```
source /opt/ros/your_distribution/setup.bash
```

Replace the *your_distribution* with the ROS distribution that you are using (kinetic, indigo, jade or else) in the above command. Then source your catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash and try to run the teleop node

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-09**:
Aslo, make sure the python script is executable (chmod +x teleop_twist_keyboard.py).

**Comment by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on 2018-07-09**:
This was the problem. Thanks!

**Comment by [prabakaran](https://answers.ros.org/users/85209/prabakaran/) on 2021-09-22**:
can you please tell me command for making a cpp file to executable file as you said for python?